Unable to Unlock Bootloader on Realme RMX3710 – Can't Access Bootloader Mode
I am trying to unlock the bootloader on my Realme RMX3710 (Android 14). I am facing issues switching the phone from Fastbootd to the standard Fastboot (Bootloader) mode.

Operating system: Linux (Ubuntu 24.04)
ADB/Fastboot versions:
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 Version 35.0.2-12147458,
fastboot version 35.0.2-12147458
OEM Unlocking is enabled in Developer Options on the phone. USB Debugging is enabled and functioning correctly.

Below are the steps I’ve taken and the results I encountered. Thank you in advance for any help!

Checking the device in ADB


Command: adb devices
Result: List of devices attached KRG6AELZT4SSAMBE device


Attempting to enter Bootloader mode via ADB


Command: adb reboot bootloader
Result: The phone restarts and boots back to normal mode.


Attempting to enter Fastbootd via ADB


Command: adb reboot fastboot
Result: The phone switches to Fastbootd.
Command: fastboot devices
Result: KRG6AELZT4SSAMBE fastbootd


Trying to switch from Fastbootd to Bootloader using Fastboot


Command:fastboot reboot bootloader
Result: The phone restarts and boots back to normal mode.


Attempting manual entry into Bootloader mode


Steps:I turn off the phone.I hold the power button and volume down button simultaneously.
Result:The phone enters Recovery mode instead of Bootloader. The Recovery menu lacks an option like Enter Fastboot Mode.


Attempting to unlock the bootloader in Fastbootd


Command:fastboot flashing unlock
Result:FAILED (remote: 'Unrecognized command flashing unlock') fastboot: error: Command failed
Command:fastboot oem unlock
Result:FAILED (remote: 'Unable to open fastboot HAL') fastboot: error: Command failed


Your phone has a MediaTek chip. Are you sure fastboot mode is the way to go? Usually MediaTek devices have special software like MTKClient.
